# Отображение Canvas с устаревшим значением scale

Tags: unity3d

Есть `Canvas`, у которого `RenderMode` установлен в `WorldSpace`.
По нажатию на переключатель, объект, к которому прикреплен компонент `Canvas`, активируется или деактивируется (вызовом `SetActive()`).

На этом же объекте висит скрипт с методом Update:

```
void Update()
{
    thisTransform.localScale = camera.orthographicSize * Vector3.one * 0.03f;
}
```

Таким образом, при изменении размера камеры, размер `Canvas` (визуально) остается неизменным. Однако, если сначала выключить объект, а потом уменьшить размер камеры, то при включении объекта, он на мгновение отрисовывается с таким размером, как он был выключен (то есть, большим). После этого Canvas становится нужного размера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исходя из [порядка вызовов методов Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html), должно все работать корректно. Ведь `рендеринг GUI` следует после `Update`. Однако, нет.

Я думал, может дело в [RectTransform](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RectTransform.html), но как я понял с мануала по 
приведённой ссылке, он пересчитывается в конце кадра, прямо перед отрисовкой. Это накладывает ограничения на обработку в методе Update данных ,которые уже имеются в RectTransform. Но, ведь я задаю **новые** значения и это ограничение не должно меня касаться?

Почему я получаю такое поведение? Как это исправить, чтобы при включении объекта, он уже был нужного размера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте менять scale канвы еще и в методе OnEnable().
н-р

```js
private void OnEnable ()
{
   thisTransform.localScale = camera.orthographicSize * Vector3.one * 0.03f;
}
```

Немного **оффтопа**. Как часто меняется размер камеры? Насколько необходимо каждый кадр проводить вычисления масштаба канвы? С точки зрения оптимизации разумно было бы при изменении размеров камеры запускать, к примеру, корутину, которая плавно меняла бы масштаб канвы от своего прежнего значения к необходимому (ну или просто моментальное изменение scale...)

Comment: Не согласен. В первом предложении как-раз я указал вариант решения, посоветовав использовать код изменения масштаба канвы не только при обновлении кадра, но и при активации объекта.

Comment: Хоть и не полностью раскрыт вопрос, других ответов нет(. `OnEnable`, действительно помог.